# Стиллер HTML кода с сайтов

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть один сайт, на котором висят обьявления. Их мне нужно достать оттуда в виде HTML кода. При этом скрипт должен выполнятся в фоне, после выключения браузера, и не должен быть превышен лимит max execution time.. Накидайте код, пожалуйста. Сам код стиллера я где-то видел в интернете, но остального не нашел.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Готового решения Вы здесь не увидите. И Как сказали Выше или фриланс или пишите сами, а мы только даём наводку.

Парсить записи - регуляркой, но надо ещё расшаривать линки, и с них опять же парсить.

Так что думаю тут легче написать программку на C#, чем возиться с ненужными кодом на PHP

Comment: @Alex_Wells, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

"Накидать" за тебя - на биржу фриланса.
Выполнение в фоне и не зависимо от браузера - легко, PHP вполне нормально выполняется в терминале, присобачить запуск по крону и тогда жизнь удалась :)
Время выполнение скрипта задать можно функцией [`set_time_limit()`.](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php)
Получение кода - много способов: от `file_get_contents(URI)` до `cURL`, в гугле полно информации на этот счёт.
P. S. Стиллер - воришка, лучше граббер - собиратель. Так оно как-то корректнее и... законнее :)